# git: removing history re-added and duplicated after filter-branch

Tags: git

**The problem**:

About 3 months ago I ran a git filter-branch on the repo to remove files larger than 10MB.  It was successful, and we required all users to re-clone and use the pruned repository.  All of the commits with large files (and those after) were rewritten.  Since then users have made hundreds of commits without issue.  Unfortunately, at one point about a month ago, a user must have force pushed (grrrr) something that resulted in the old history commits coming back alongside the modified ones.  An example of this is below:

```
commit 39fc52e328a40a4762a1a2dfe01e9ee3d57d9f22
Author: ***
Date:   Wed May 11 18:54:37 2022 -0400

    Doxygen error fixes for client

commit 00de51838e92abb0f65c474d35f010a562b95383
Author: ***
Date:   Wed May 11 18:54:37 2022 -0400

    Doxygen error fixes for client
```

The first commit is the (correct) filter-branch modified commit that has the large file removed.  The second commit is the original (incorrect) commit that still contains the large file.

**My question**:

I need to find some way to re-remove the duplicate commits that were re-added.  I know I can re-run filter-branch to get the large files out again, but the customer really doesn't want the duplicate history in there.

How would I go about doing that?

**What I've tried:**

I have tried rebasing in multiple ways with no success.  As I mentioned, this repo has thousands of commits--hundreds are dupes, and hundreds surround the range of commits I need to remove.  When I try to do a:

`git rebase -i --root`

and remove a single commit I get a non-stop string of merge conflicts back to the HEAD.

I've also tried just doing a `git rebase --onto <bad-hash> <good-hash>` with the same result.

I'm ok with git in general, but I think I'm out of my league here.  I'm also fine with writing python and BASH scripts to fix this and have full server-side access to the repo.

Thanks in advance for the advice.  Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: You literally cannot remove a commit from any repository. You can only *add* commits. The filter-branch command works by duplicating the old (lousy) commits into new (improved) commits. The filter-repo command works by building an entire new repository, separate from the old repository; the new repository has only the new commits, and the old repository has the old commits. You may find using filter-repo better fits your needs.

Comment: Note that rebase *also* works by copying commits to new-and-improved commits; it's just that rebase is intended to work on just a few commits, while the filter-* commands tend to be ones you use over an entire repository.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, torek.  I will try to run a filter-repo command to remove commits that match hashes from the old history.